# Cybersource microform session API giving 400 bad request

Tags: cybersource

I am trying to generate the captureContext using the Flex microform session API but the response comes as a bad request: 400. I contacted CyberSource support they confirmed that the request body I am generating is all fine and there is something with your headers only.
So they provided me with one developer portal, [link here](https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#flex-microform_microform-integration_generate-capture-context_samplerequests-dropdown_generate-capture-context-simple_liveconsole-tab-request-body), to test with my sandbox credentials, headers, and request body. There I am able to get the capture context but when the same headers information I try to put in my dot net http client call then it doesn't work.

Here the support team is also not helping by saying that this is out of their scope.

I am using below code

```
var digest = $"{GenerateDigest(jsonBody)}";
            Console.WriteLine($"digest is {digest}");
            var rawPostStringForSignature = $"host:apitest.cybersource.com@date: {DateTime.Now:r}@(request-target): post /microform/v2/sessions/@digest:{digest}@v-c-merchant-id:mymerchant_id";
            var postStringForSignature = rawPostStringForSignature.Replace("@", Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine("Headers: " + postStringForSignature);
            var signatureHash = GenerateSignatureFromParams(postStringForSignature, "vxxxx8leqzxxxxxxxxOgSYDlxg57JldRuk=");
            var signatureHeader = $"keyid = \"48xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-87a4-99xxxxxxc\", algorithm = \"HmacSHA256\", headers = \"host date (request-target) digest v-c-merchant-id\", signature = \"{signatureHash}\"";
            Console.WriteLine($"Signature header: {signatureHeader}");

            #region API CALL
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://apitest.cybersource.com/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                                     .Accept
                                     .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("v-c-merchant-id", "mymerchant_id");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("date", $"{DateTime.Now:r}");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("host", "apitest.cybersource.com");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("digest", $"{digest}");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("signature", $"{signatureHeader}");

                // serialize your json using newtonsoft json serializer then add it to the StringContent
                var content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var result = await client.PostAsync("microform/v2/sessions", content);
                try
                {
                    string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    Console.WriteLine("Request: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(client));
                    Console.WriteLine("Response: " + resultContent);
                }
```

so not sure what is the mistake in the header which is causing to generate the bad request.

FYI: All the merchant_id, access key, security key that I use on developer portal works fine but here it doesn't work.

I am also generating the digest and signature dynamically with the following methods:

```
public static string GenerateDigest(string reqBody)
    {
        var digest = "";
        var bodyText = reqBody;
        using (var sha256hash = SHA256.Create())
        {
            byte[] payloadBytes = sha256hash
                .ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyText));
            digest = Convert.ToBase64String(payloadBytes);
            digest = "SHA-256=" + digest;
        }
        return digest;
    }
    public static string GenerateSignatureFromParams(string signatureParams, string secretKey)
    {
        var sigBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signatureParams);
        var decodedSecret = Convert.FromBase64String(secretKey);
        var hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(decodedSecret);
        var messageHash = hmacSha256.ComputeHash(sigBytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(messageHash);
    }
```